# How to return Max 10 Items in collectionview numberOfItemsInSection from JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview

I am getting Json response like below

```
   detailsDB = ProductDetailsData(dictionary: NSDictionary())

   func serviceCall(){
let param = ["jsonrpc": "2.0",
             "params": ["product_id" : productID
             ]] as [String : Any]

APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param, vc: self, url: getUrl(of: .product_details), header: header) {(responseData) in
  
        self.detailsDB = ProductDetailsData(dictionary: responseData.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
}
```

like this i am getting all products in JSON are showing in collectionview.. here **i need to show max 10 products from JSON to collectionview**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return detailsDB?.result?.seller_products?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VerticalSliderCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! VerticalSliderCollectionCell
   
    let indexData = detailsDB?.result?.seller_products?[indexPath.item]
    cell.imgProduct.getImage(strUrl: "\(productImagePath)\(indexData?.default_image?.image ?? "")")
    cell.lblTitle.text = indexData?.product_by_language?.title
    cell.lbRealPrice.text = indexData?.discount_price != "0.000" ? "\(indexData?.price ?? "") KWD" : ""
    cell.lblDiscountedPrice.text = indexData?.discount_price != "0.000" ? "\(indexData?.discount_price ?? "") KWD" : "\(indexData?.price ?? "") KWD"
   
    return cell
}
```

please do help me to solve this error

Comment: use : min(detailsDB?.result?.seller_products?.count ?? 0, 10)

Comment: Simply write this logic in `numberOfItemsInSection`, something like:
`return min(10, detailsDB?.result?.seller_products?.count ?? 0)`

Comment: Once again, do not use `NS...` collection types in Swift. You throw away the type information. Use native types `Array` and `Dictionary`

Comment: Take prefix 10 items from your parsed data source

Comment: @RajaKishan, okay, then how to show data in `cellForItemAt `

Comment: it will automatically fetch based on the index no need to do anything for cellForItem

Comment: @RajaKishan, Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: everything is fine. Add break point and trace the error.

Comment: @RajaKishan, if there are more then 10 then 10 products are coming...
but i need if there are below 10 means need to show 4, 5 products also... please do help

Comment: Eilon's code 
min(10, detailsDB?.result?.seller_products?.count ?? 0)
if (detailsDB?.result?.seller_products?.count ?? 0) >= 10 {
     return 10
} else {
     return detailsDB?.result?.seller_products?.count ?? 0
}

What else do you want?

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return min(detailsDB?.count, 10) // 10 = max items
}
```